Extract specific text from the image
I need to extract employer Identification number from the image I tried using normal PyMpdf method etc.. I finally come across cv2 which is not much familiar with. Is there any solution to extract the specific text.
Image Data
import cv2
import pytesseract
import re
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import streamlit as st

def bounding_boxes(img_list, show_boxes):
    boxes = {}
    for curr_img in img_list:
        img = cv2.imread(curr_img)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, ksize=(9, 9), sigmaX=0)
        thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 30)
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 9))
        dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilate, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        temp = []
        for contour in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 10000:
                continue
            temp.append([x, y, w, h])
            if show_boxes:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(255, 0, 255), thickness=3)
        if show_boxes:
            img = cv2.resize(img, (500, 700), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            st.image(image=img, caption=curr_img)
        boxes[curr_img] = temp
    print('Contours saved Successfully!')
    return boxes

def extract_text(boxes):
    text = ''
    for key in boxes:
        img = cv2.imread(key)
        for x, y, w, h in boxes[key]:
            cropped_image = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            _, thresh = cv2.threshold(cropped_image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
            text += str(pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config='--psm 6'))
    print('Text Extraction Completed!')
    return text

filename = '/home/flock/Documents/pdf_extraction/ein_number_extraction/images/page0.jpg'
img_list = [filename]
show_boxes = False
boxes = bounding_boxes(img_list, show_boxes)
print(boxes)


Welcome to StackOverflow! You probably want to redact the data in that image, just in case™.
